# Store the existing value and the new input value and calculate a result

Tags: excel, vba, collections

The purpose is that the user types the new value into the cell during a counting task instead of recalculating again and again.

```vb
Dim OldValues As New Collection 'Variable to store OldValues

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Or Target.Count > 1 Or TypeName(Target) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub 'exclude buttons, shapes areas multiple selections
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    Dim CelL As Range
    For Each CelL In Target
        OldValues.Add CelL.Value, CelL.Address 'put value to collection
    Next CelL
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Or Target.Count > 1 Or TypeName(Target) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub 'same like above
On Local Error Resume Next
    Dim CelL As Range, ValInput As Long, ValOffsetLong As Long, ValOld As Long, ValNew As Long, ValOffsetString As String, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim keyCells As Range: Set keyCells = Range("C12:C19,C22:C29")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set keyCells = Application.Union(keyCells.Precedents, keyCells)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, keyCells) Is Nothing Then
        r = Target.Row ' using this to find the target address
        c = Target.Column ' using this to find the target address
        ValInput = Target.Value ' store the input
        ValOffsetLong = Target.Offset(163, 11) ' find the offset value
        ValOffsetString = Target.Offset(163, 11).Address(0, 0) ' find the offset address
        ValOld = OldValues(CelL.Adress) ' taking the value from SelectionChange
        ValNew = ValInput + ValOld - ValOffsetLong ' calculate
        For Each CelL In Target
            Debug.Print "/SelctedCell(Target): " & CelL.Address & " /Input(CelL.Value): " & CelL.Value & " /ValInput: " & Target.Value _
              & " /ValOld: " & OldValues(CelL.Address) & " /ValOffsetLong: " & ValOffsetLong & " /ValNew " & ValNew & " /ValOffsetString: " & ValOffsetString
            Cells(r, c).Formula = "=" & ValNew & "+" & ValOffsetString 'write the needed formula again in cell
        Next CelL
    End If
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    For Each CelL In Target
        OldValues.Add CelL.Value, CelL.Address
    Next CelL
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The script should

- save the cell value of the selected cell when changing or activating the cell
- save the new input value when changing the cell (new value)
- store a third value resulting from other calculations in a variable (offset)
- put the whole thing into a result variable and write a formula into the active cell with this new value.

With `Debug.Print` I can see all variables are correct. Nevertheless always a wrong result comes out.
The calculation of the variable "ValNew" doesn't seem to work.
It seems the old Value (from the collection "OldValues") is empty when I press Enter.

Before (empty cell or cell with a number or cell with formula)
[image: Cell Range C22:C29]

Then enter a number which is added to the current cell value but without the value of cell N190 (enter 10) the script should store the cell value in collection `OldValues` store the input `ValInput = Target.Value` then take the input value, add the old value subtract the offset value and write a formula with this result (+ offset adress) `ValNew = ValInput + ValOld - ValOffsetLong` but:
[image: result]

It seems that only the Input Value will be processed since the old value was 1 the new is 10 +N190 = 12 but the result shows 9 +N190 means to me `ValNew = ValInput - ValOffsetLong` had been processed and `ValNew = ValInput + ValOld - ValOffsetLong` not. ValOld is not empty but ignored.
[image: print of variables]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I really tried to understand your requirement, but it is not clear - at least for me. It would help if you show us some sample data and your expected result. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `ValOld = OldValues(CelL.Adress)` won't get anything in your `Worksheet_Change` event if you don't set your CelL to anything there. Did you mean to use `ValOld = OldValues(Target.Adress)`? Or `Set CelL = Target`

Comment: Thx for your answer but I do not understand why `Debug.Print  OldValues(CelL.Address)` shows the Value stored in `Selection.Change` event and calculating with `OldValues(CelL.Address)` is impossible. Has it something to do with a value in the collection `OldValues`?

Comment: @Ike-> simply I want to input in the same cell and the output should be "existing value in cell + input value in cell + offset value". ... I am not sure how to explain it better, I am sorry.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a "Before", "Desired output" and perhaps a "Current Output" example?

Comment: I'm not sure if this appears clearer now ¿? Unfortunately, I can not yet embed pictures, because I am missing the points ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still is very challenging to understand your requirement (not your issues regarding your own code ...)

Try this code - it has to go into the sheets module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private m_colOldValues As Collection

Private Property Get rgKeyCells() As Range
    Set rgKeyCells = Me.Range("B5:B11") '---> adjust this to your needs 
    Me.Range("C12:C19,C22:C29")
End Property

Private Property Get rgOffset(c As Range) As Range
    Set rgOffset = c.Offset(, 2) '---> adjust this to your needs: c.Offset(163, 11)
End Property

Private Sub readOldValues()
    Dim c As Range
    Set m_colOldValues = New Collection
    For Each c In rgKeyCells.Cells
        m_colOldValues.Add c.Value - rgOffset(c).Value, c.Address
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub updateCell(c As Range)
    c.Value = "=" & c.Value & " + " & m_colOldValues(c.Address) & " + " & rgOffset(c).Address
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, rgKeyCells) Is Nothing Then
            updateCell c
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    readOldValues
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If m_colOldValues Is Nothing Then
        readOldValues
    End If
End Sub
```

I used the following setup:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Ike, unfortunately I do not understand even in the rudiment what you have done here and why... it would be great if you could explain your idea to me, if possible so that even a goofball can understand it. I need to combine multiple ranges with multiple offsets in the future, maybe it's easier to do with this setup?

Comment: One basic programming rule is: each sub should only handle one task. You have two basic tasks: 1) Reading current values from a given range (incl. subtraction of the offset-value) into a collection -> `Sub readOldValues` 2) Updating the value of a given cell with your special logic -> `Sub updateCell`. To simplify further (or make the code easier to adjust) I added a property `rgKeyCells`. And a property that returns the offset for a given cell, using a defined logic (in my case "offset by 2 columns"). When `Worksheet_Change`-event occurs you put these code pieces together to tell the "story"

Comment: Even though I still don't understand why many sub-calls are better than one (doesn't that make the whole thing slower?) I find the solution smart. Also with the idea to show the Input+OldVal+Address I am very happy. Basically the input person can then see better what he has done (at least until the next step).

Comment: No - code isn't slower due to sub-calls - but maintenance-friendly, reusable etc.

Comment: What if I ask for help to set up a second offset for some KeyCells? Would you help me to solve this problem or do I have to ask a new question? My intention is to have as little VBA as possible, but as much flexibility as possible. I envision expanding the KeyCells to include the `Me.Range ... , C30:C39, C52:C65")` and then `If KeyCells = ("C30:C39")` activate another offset, so that the offset for C30:C39 is e.g. `190, 12` for C52:C65 `120, 15` and so on.... does this make sense, can it be understood? Is this how it should be done?

Comment: What you are asking for is teaching you Excel and VBA. But SO is to solve specific programming problems. Start looking into named ranges, INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP-functions. I am pretty sure you should setup your sheets in a different way to solve the offset part and you should be able to use formulas to retrieve the relevant data.

Comment: As I wrote at the beginning, I am a noob to VBA :) but not to Excel. So far I have solved everything with on the way you suggested (I would say probably more complex than expectet by you) however I now have a problem with an input mask that I am not allowed to change and many results that I generate elsewhere (for example this function is for that)... but anyway, thank you very much i aprechiate your help :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Was about to comment again that I'm breaking my own head about this as to why I was able to get the Target.Address (the funky CelL isn't necessary if you're only looking for a singular cell anyway) BUT I believe I found the main root of your problem:

> On Error Resume Next

The bane of everyone's error-solving issues to be honest and I should've seen it earlier being the reason *why* I couldn't find the issue.

```
ValOld = OldValues(CelL.Adress) 'your address is missing an extra d
```

Your full code could look like this then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Or Target.Count > 1 Or TypeName(Target) <> "Range" Then
        Debug.Print "Got to exit sub"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    OldValues.Add Target.Value, Target.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Or Target.Count > 1 Or TypeName(Target) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    On Local Error Resume Next
    Dim ValInput As Long, ValOffsetLong As Long, ValOld As Long, ValNew As Long, ValOffsetString As String
    Dim keyCells As Range: Set keyCells = Range("C12:C19,C22:C29")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set keyCells = Application.Union(keyCells.Precedents, keyCells)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, keyCells) Is Nothing Then
        ValInput = Target.Value
        ValOffsetLong = Target.Offset(163, 11)
        ValOffsetString = Target.Offset(163, 11).Address(0, 0)
        ValOld = OldValues.Item(Target.Address)
        ValNew = ValInput + ValOld - ValOffsetLong
        Debug.Print "/SelctedCell(Target): " & Target.Address & " /Input(Target.Value): " & Target.Value & " /ValInput: " & Target.Value _
                    & " /ValOld: " & OldValues(Target.Address) & " /ValOffsetLong: " & ValOffsetLong & " /ValNew " & ValNew & " /ValOffsetString: " & ValOffsetString
        Target.Formula = "=" & ValNew & "+" & ValOffsetString
    End If
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    OldValues.Add Target.Value, Target.Address
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But as to why you subtract the offset value just to add it again later, I'm not so sure :)

Comment: Thanks Notus, works great and my (your) VBA is also much cleaner and leaner, thanks for removing the useless baggage. I see you changed the handling of the collection `CLng(OldValues.Item(Target.Address) * 1)` converts a string to long as far as I know, I tried that before but obviously did something wrong.  However, I don`t understand why you use `* 1`, surely this works without? (Why I subtract offset to add it back? This is just for visualization, 90% of the end users can't do anything with it but for 10% it's surely helpful to see where the added value comes from).

Comment: ... and the formula is a need since the value in the offset area could be changed separately (also depending on a formula contained there)

Comment: My bad, that was still some code trying to force it to get into the variable since I hadn't seen the adress vs address part :') The added value doesn't come from the offset because that cancels each other out, no? You remove it and add it so it doesn't matter how much you put into that offset cell, it won't make any difference to your other used cells. I'll change my code since the conversion isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Hi Notus, I would vote for both answers if I could. Thx again and no harm ;-)

Comment: Np, as long as you're helped (and others as well), all good!